# Simple string title is not updating when using hot reload

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

**Hot reload** is not working in a simple `Hello World` example. When trying to change the `text`, a `string`, to something else under run-time and hot reload it, nothing happens. I'm debugging on a *physical* device and I'm using *VSCode*.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  String text = "Hello world";
      runApp(Center(child: new Text(text, textDirection: TextDirection.ltr)));
}
```

Is **hot reload** not reliable or am i doing something wrong here?

*EDIT: Found out that restarting the app, CTRL+SHIFT+F5, worked as the hot reload should.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Specifically, a hot reload causes all the existing widgets to rebuild. Only code involved in the rebuilding of the widgets are automatically re-executed.

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/hot-reload

This means that you need a widget class which implements the `build` method to ensure the code is going to be re-executed on a hot reload.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String text = "Hello world";
    return Center(
      child: new Text(text, textDirection: TextDirection.ltr),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you create your class like this i think there are no problems :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  String  text="Hello World"
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            body: Center(
      child: Text(text,textDirection: TextDirection.ltr),
    )));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> A few types of code changes ***cannot be hot reloaded*** though:
>
> - Global variable initializers
> - Static field initializers
> - The `main()` method of the app
>
> For these changes you can fully restart your application, without having to end your > debugging session:
>
> - Don’t click the Stop button; simply re-click the Run button (if in a run session) or Debug button (if in a debug session), or shift-click the ‘hot reload’ button.

Found this on the [Flutter developer portal](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/android-studio#hot-reload-vs-full-app-restart).